# Django File Storage: Add passwords to file names

Tags: django, django-storage

We use Python Django.

I want to store user-uploaded files in the following way:

`/<INTEGER>/<HASH>/<FILE>`

`<INTEGER>` is a subfolder which is meant to contain max 1000 files.

`<HASH>` is a secret code individual for each file, to prevent hackers to download a somebody's other file from our HTTPS server.

`<FILE>` is the filename.

How to write a Django storage implementing this?

First, can I derive my class from `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage` or I need to derived from `django.core.files.storage.Storage` directly?

Second, which methods should I override? Should I override `save`? It seems yes, because it is best to generate the hash only when saving, but I am unsure I can do in `save` what I need. What about overriding `_save`? Also: what's about overriding `get_available_name` and/or `generate_filename`? They seem not be quite tailored to my needs, because it would be better to generate the hash only when actually saving the file, not just when considering its name.

So, what to do?

Comment: I would rephrase `<PASSWORD>` to `<HASH>` as its confusing and kind of a red flag :)

Comment: You probably don't want to do this for all uploads globally just for the ones that are sensitive, and you can do it on a per field basis by writing your own [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) function.

Comment: @Anonymous I want **all** uploads to be secured by placing them into a directory with a secret name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for `generate_filename` in `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`. I find it more appropriate since than I still have the nice safety cushion in `get_available_name`.
I also wouldn't worry about getting filename in cases when the file is not being saved, just need to make sure that the hash generating is cheap enough.

---

```
# settings.py

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage.CustomStorage'
```

---

```
# app/storage.py

from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
import random

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class CustomStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        # implement smarter hash creation method here
        some_hash = hashlib.md5('{}-{}'.format('filename', datetime.now().isoformat())).hexdigest()

        return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(random.randint(0, 1000), some_hash, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can have your own function to handle the way you want to create folder structure and  you can have in models.py as  
attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=change_file_path, blank=True, null=True)
 
where change_file_path is your custom function to create the desired folder structure

Comment: This is not a solution: 1. the hash is a unique string generated *when uploading the file*, individual for each file. 2. It should work for **every** `FileField` not set individually for each file. So I need to create a custom storage, not just set `upload_to` manually!

Answer (score 0):

Using both `storage` and `upload_to` arguments for setting the upload directory.More info [FileField django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

Here I am using uuid as `<HASH>` (**you could change using your own hash generator**),max_num is `<integer>` and senfile is `<FILE>` in Django model

models.py

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import uuid

storeFile = FileSystemStorage(location='SensitiveFiles/')

def content_file_upload(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.max_num,str(uuid.uuid4()), filename)

class SensitiveFiles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    senfile = models.FileField(storage=storeFile,upload_to=content_file_upload,validators=[validation_for_max_num_files])
    max_num=models.IntegerField(default=1000)

    def get_file_url(self):
        return self.senfile.url
```

Create your validators for checking current number of files in uploaded directory.

Comment: This is not a solution: 1. the hash is a unique string generated *when uploading the file*, individual for each file. 2. It should work for **every** `FileField` not set individually for each file. So I need to create a custom storage, not just set `upload_to` manually!